# Math Set Functions on Associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array, intersection

How to get the difference of two associative arrays in Javascript.?
example :

```
var arr1[0] = { name : 'test1' , type : 'test2' };
var arr1[1] = { name : 'test2' , type : 'test3' };
var arr2[0] = { name : 'test1' , type : 'test2' };
var arr2[1] = { name : 'test3' , type : 'test4' };
```

I need to get output like this

```
if Intersection() :
arr3[0] = { name : 'test1' , type : 'test2' }
if difference arr1-arr2 :
arr4[0] = { name : 'test2' , type : 'test3' };
if difference arr2-arr1 :
arr5[0] = { name : 'test3' , type : 'test4' };
```

I didn't find anything pertaining to associative array in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function equals(a, b){
       return (a.name === b.name && a.type === b.type);            
    }

    function has(arr, obj){
        var len = arr.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(equals(arr[i], obj)) return true;                               
        }

        return false;        
    }    

    function clone(obj){
        return {
            name: obj.name,
            type: obj.type
        };        
    }


    function intersect(a, b){
        var common = [];    
        if(!a.length || !b.length) return common;

        var aLen = a.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < aLen; i++){
            if(has(b, a[i])){
                common.push(clone(a[i]));   
            }            
        }

        return common;              
    }




    function subtract(a, b){
       var result = [];    
        if(!a.length || !b.length) return result;

        var common = intersect(a, b);
        var aLen = a.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < aLen; i++){
            if(!has(common, a[i])){
                result.push(clone(a[i]));   
            }               
        }

        return result;
    }

    var arr1 = [{ name : 'test1' , type : 'test2' },{ name : 'test2' , type : 'test3' }];

    var arr2 = [{ name : 'test1' , type : 'test2' }, { name : 'test3' , type : 'test4' }];

    console.log(intersect(arr1, arr2));
    console.log(subtract(arr1, arr2));
    console.log(subtract(arr2, arr1));
```